# Add HTML code without using innerHTML or insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, innerhtml

How can I display the data using the ts file 
without help of innerHTML

```
const object = {
  piece: 11,
  amount: 2200,
  quantity: 33,
};

this.summaryResult =  `<a class= "nav-Invoice">
  <div>
     <span class="fl" >` + object.piece + `</span>
     <span class="fr" >` + object.quantity + `</span>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="divblock">
      <b>$ ` + object.amount + `</b>
  </span>
</a>`
```

HTML File:-

```
{{summaryResult}}
```

Result:-

```
       11                     33
                2200
```

Comment: This is not really an "Angular" approach. You should check *ngFor or *ngIf with some templating and {{}} variables instead.

Comment: Actually the variable is displaying dynamically in table.

Comment: Yes, this is what `{{ }}` is meant for, dynamic variables / HTML binding. Check the "tour of heroes" by Angular to know more about that (https://angular.io/tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

You really should do that with some Angular templating instead of even thinking about using the innerHTML object.

summary.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html'
})
export class SummaryComponent {
  public object = {
    piece: 11,
    amount: 2200,
    quantity: 33, 
  };

  constructor() {}

  /* Your object logic here */
}
```

summary.component.html:

```
<a *ngIf="object" class="nav-Invoice">
  <div>
     <span class="fl">{{ object.piece }}</span>
     <span class="fr">{{ object.quantity }}</span>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="divblock">
      <b>$ {{ object.amount }}</b>
  </span>
</a>
```

The two files must be in the same folder and the Component must be declared in an Angular module.

Comment: `public object = {`  `public` is unnecessary here as public is default type for class members in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the DOM in ts file also.

in HTML file:

```
<div #inputBox><div>
```

in ts file:

```
const object = {
  piece: 11,
  amount: 2200,
  quantity: 33,
};

const aTag = document.createElement('a');

const innerDivTag = document.createElement('div');

const spanPiece = document.createElement('span');
const spanQuantity = document.createElement('span');
const clearFixDiv = document.createElement('div');

spanPiece.innerHTML = object.piece;
spanQuantity .innerHTML = object.quantity;
innerDivTag.appendChild(spanPiece);
innerDivTag.appendChild(spanQuantity);
innerDivTag.appendChild(clearFixDiv);
aTag.appendChild(innerDivTag);

const outerSpan = document.createElement('span');
outerSpan .innerHTML = object.amount;
aTag.appendChild(outerSpan);

this.inputBox.nativeElement.appendChild(aTag);
```

Comment: Actually the content is loading dynamically in table , so can't finds its ID

Comment: This is painful to watch. Guys, this is **not** how Angular is supposed to work... Please learn about components and templating, this is what your project should look like: https://stackblitz.com/angular/jejqydqopkv. And don't tell me your stuff is dynamic, Angular is __meant__ for dynamic bindings.